# Eclipse PDT - highlight active indent guide selection

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

for having indent guide in Eclipse, I use plugin **Indent Guide**, but what I miss, is to highlight active part.

See the difference between Notepad++ and Eclipse

[image]

When viewing large parts of code, I need to have highligted the active part of if clause/function/etc.

Thank you.

Comment: There is already a feature request that you can comment on https://github.com/sschaef/IndentGuide/issues/12

Comment: Thank you for the info, commented on Github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already an open feature request that you can comment on:

[**Indent Guide issue #12: *Highlight on brace matching***](http://github.com/sschaef/IndentGuide/issues/12)